# Overwrite JSDoc in extending module class without redeclaration

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Assumed this ...

```js
`use strict;`

class Foo
{
    /**
     * Description
     * @param {Type} arg blabla
     */
    doSomething( arg )
    {
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    /**
     * Overwrite the description for `doSomething()` without redeclaring the method itself.
     * @param {Type} arg blabla
     */
    // dosomething( arg )
    // {
    // }
}
```

This is a very simplified nonsense example. The reason in reallife is ...

I have a common collection which accepts mixed elements for some methods like add, replace, remove, etc.. I have a second collection specialized for managing HTTP headers. E. g. I like to change the doc of the `add()` from "Adds an element to the collection" to "Adds an HTTP header to the collection". The method itself stays as is.

I tried

```js
class Bar extends Foo
{
    /**
     * Overwrite the description for `doSomething()` without redeclaring the method itself.
     * @param {Type} arg blabla
     * @method dosomething
     * @memberOf {Foo}
     */
}
```

in various ways ... with @override, @inheritdoc, etc.

How to achieve this?